# Detecting that a YouTube video was muted for copyright violations

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to determine if a video being played through YouTube's JavaScript API has been muted for copyright infringements. YouTube's player happily plays the video, no error is thrown, so I'm wondering if there's some flag buried in metadata. I don't see anything in documentation. Is anyone privvy to this?

Here's a video which is muted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1poQE-mItpc

Here's my query to the API explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=id%252C+snippet%252C+contentDetails%252C+liveStreamingDetails%252C+player%252C+recordingDetails%252C+status&id=1poQE-mItpc&_h=9&

Its response:

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"_Ao29TLrEE22AhzAvL5Tljx-d60/A5Vud3OI5QeD0pFgKANC76SsTQY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"_Ao29TLrEE22AhzAvL5Tljx-d60/do1XMt-hqrCVUBNaQDjiNU9IwZM\"",
   "id": "1poQE-mItpc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-01-14T11:54:53.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCdX5ZAvFi9G5fZz3vGyGemw",
    "title": "魔奇少年 magi Season 2 ED 2/Ending 2 TVsize",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1poQE-mItpc/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1poQE-mItpc/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1poQE-mItpc/hqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1poQE-mItpc/sddefault.jpg"
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/1poQE-mItpc/maxresdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "弒夜雪",
    "categoryId": "10",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1M30S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false
   },
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   },
   "player": {
    "embedHtml": "<iframe type='text/html' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/1poQE-mItpc' width='640' height='360' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true'/>"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Wondering the same thing

Comment: I did not. I've worked with the YouTube API pretty much daily for ~2 years and still have no idea if this is possible. Boooo.